# merge excel cells using pyExcelerator

Tags: python, xlwt, pyexcelerator

I want to merge two cells in excel using pyExcelerator ,

> ws.write_merge(r1=0,r2=1,c1=0, c2=0, label='test1', style=style1)
>       #merge cell1(row=0, column=0) with cell2(row=1, column=0)

Why the errors happen?
  AssertionErrors,0 < 0 errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the package author put an assertion in Cell.py that would blow up if he ever tried to write a MULBLANKS record with too few columns. Your one-column-wide merged cells block stepped on the mine.

Suggestion: Instead of pyExcelerator, use xlwt. xlwt is a fork of pyExcelerator, with many bugs fixed (including this one) and several enhancements. pyExcelerator is believed not to be under maintenance. xlwt will run almost all code that works on pyExcelerator. The exceptions are not in demand by xlwt users.

[This site](http://www.python-excel.org/) will lead you to the download site and inform you about the sibling xlrd and xlutils packages.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of xlwt and author of xlrd.

**Update** This bug is mentioned in the pyExcelerator tracker on sourceforge. However the suggested fix is not one that I would recommend. Just get xlwt.